# Want help to concatenate my tokens and phrases again to form a string after stemming them

Tags: python, string, concatenation, nltk, arabic

I have a string called `keywords`, it consists of some sentences separated by `-` mark. I want to get the stem of each word in my `keywords` variable *while keeping it with the same form (each phrase in it separated by `-` mark)*

I have tried to do this through splitting each phrase in `keywords` using `.split()` function then tokenizing each phrase to single words then stem them. but I couldn't concatenate the output to form the same as in `keywords` variable. Here is the attempt:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.isri import ISRIStemmer

stemmer = ISRIStemmer()
keywords =" الاسلام-التوحيد-الكافرون-افتراؤهم علي الله و تكذيبهم و جدالهم- النبوة-اثبات نبوته وصدق ما جاء به-وظيفته وصدق ما اوحى اليه"
phrases = keywords.split("-")
for phrase in phrases:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(phrase)
    for token in tokens:
        stemmedTokens = stemmer.stem(token)
```

This gives me each stemmed word separately like this:

```
سلم
وحد
كفر
فرؤ
علي
الل
و
كذب
...
```

But I want the output to be exactly like this:

```
 سلم-وحد-كفر-فرؤ علي الل و كذب وجدل-نبةاثب نبة صدق ما جاء به-وظف صدق ما وحي اليه
```

I want each word to be stemmed and represented in a string variable with the same form of `keywords` variable which is:

```
" الاسلام-التوحيد-الكافرون-افتراؤهم علي الله و تكذيبهم و جدالهم- النبوة-اثبات نبوته وصدق ما جاء به-وظيفته وصدق ما اوحى اليه"
```

Any help?

Comment: Try to put a corresponding English example for non-Arabians so that you could get more answers :-)

Comment: Looks like something's not quite right with your code. Right now `stemmedTokens` is a string that gets replaced with the output of `stemmer.stem(token)`. When the loop is done you'll end up with a single string of the last result. The output you show looks like a list. However, what you need to do is `join` the list `stemmedTokens` with a whitespace (creating a string of the phrase), and put this string in a list of `stemmedPhrases` and in turn join this list with a "-".

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want to add a `-` after the inner loop. So that your code would be:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.isri import ISRIStemmer

stemmer = ISRIStemmer()

keywords =" الاسلام-التوحيد-الكافرون-افتراؤهم علي الله و تكذيبهم و جدالهم- النبوة-اثبات نبوته وصدق ما جاء به-وظيفته وصدق ما اوحى اليه"
phrases = keywords.split("-")
stemmedTokens = []
for phrase in phrases:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(phrase)
    for token in tokens:
        stemmedTokens = stemmer.stem(token)
    stemmedTokens.append("-") if i + 1 is not len(phrases) else None
```

Also, you can use list comprehension :)

```
stemmedTokens = []
for i, phrase in enumerate(phrases):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(phrase)
    [stemmedTokens.append(stemmer.stem(token)) for token in tokens]
    stemmedTokens.append("-") if i + 1 is not len(phrases) else None
```